# I am setting up authentication using google-oauth and passport but i am facing an error in fetching user profile

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, node-modules, passport-google-oauth

This is the code i used for authentication using google oauth and I am facing an error in setting up authentication. I am uanble to fetch the user profile. Due to which i am not able to authenticate my user. Please help me to resolve this issue.
Here is the code that i have used:-

```
//jshint esversion:6
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// const encrypt = require('mongoose-encryption');
// const md5 = require('md5');
// const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
// const saltRounds = 10;
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(session({
  secret: "Our little Secret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
const url = ("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB");
mongoose.connect(url);
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  googleId: {
    type: String
  }
});
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);
// userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: process.env.SECRET,encryptedFields: ["password"] });
const User = new mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
// passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
// passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user);
 });

 passport.deserializeUser(async function (id, done) {
     try {
         const user = await User.findById(id);
         done(null, user);
     } catch (err) {
         done(err, null);
     }
 });
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb){
    User.findOrCreate({
      googleId: profile.id
    }, function(err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }));
app.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.render("home");
  });
app.route('/auth/google')
  .get(passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ["profile"]
  }));
app.route('/auth/google/secrets')
.get(passport.authenticate('google',{failureRedirect: '/login'}),(req,res)=>{
  res.redirect('/secrets');
});
app.route('/login')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.render("login");
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    const user = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
    });
    req.login(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
          res.redirect("/secrets");
        });
      }
    });
    // User.findOne({
    //   email: username
    // }).then((foundItem) => {
    //   if (foundItem.password===password){
    //     res.render("secrets");
    //   }
    // }).catch((err)=>{
    //   console.log(err);
    // })
    // bcrypt.compare(password,foundItem.password, function(err, result) {
    //   if (result === true) {
    //     res.render("secrets");
    //   }
    // });
    // }).catch((err)=>{
    //   console.log(err);
    // });
  });
app.route('/register')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.render("register");
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    // bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    //   const newUser = new User({
    //     email: req.body.username,
    //     password: hash
    //   });
    //   newUser.save().then(() => {
    //     res.render("secrets");
    //   }).catch((err) => {
    //     console.log(err);
    //   });
    // });
    User.register({
      username: req.body.username
    }, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/register");
      } else {
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
          res.redirect("/secrets");
        });
      }
    });
  });
app.route("/secrets")
  .get(function(req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.render("secrets");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
  });
app.route("/logout")
  .get(function(req, res) {
    req.logout(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    res.redirect("/");
  });
const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("The app is running on the port " + port);
});
```

The error which i faced is given below

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vikas\OneDrive\Documents\Secrets\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```